# Resize a fabricjs rect to maintain border size

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to resize a fabricjs rect instead of scale it, but I'm seeing weird behaviour while dragging the resize handles. The border starts to disappear or duplicate. I've tried both the stable version 1.7.19 and the beta 2.0.0 of fabricjs.

Here is the essence of the code I'm using:

```
canvas.on('object:scaling', function(){
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject(),
        width = obj.width,
        height = obj.height,
        scaleX = obj.scaleX,
        scaleY = obj.scaleY;

    obj.set({
        width : width * scaleX,
        height : height * scaleY,
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1
    });
});
```

Working example here: https://codepen.io/bramchi/pen/GMLYEV/

Try scaling it up and down a bit by dragging the resize handles.

[Screenshot of scaling up and down issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr1jg.png)

What I would expect to happen is the rectangle growing and shrinking while dragging the handles, and the border size to stay the same. But somehow rendering starts to go bonkers if you cross 270px or so. When the mouse button is released, it renders properly again.

What am I doing wrong? Who knows a fix? Or could this be a bug in the library I can report?

Answer (score 1):

Disable object caching to avoid this rendering behaviour:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
```

For performance reasons [Fabric.js caches objects](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching) by default during `drag` `rotate` `skew` and `scale` operations. One of the moderators of the fabric.js repo pointed me in the right direction, hooray for him!

Comment: disabling caching completely is maybe an overkill depending on the project

Answer (score 1):

as described here:

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching ( really last line )

disabling noScaleCache is enough.
That gives you caching anyway, just it invalidates cache everytime you scale the object.

Not that caching a rect is that usefull, but if you have the same behaviour for complex paths, that is still a good thing to have.

```
  new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    stroke: 'gray',
    fill: 'lightgray',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    noScaleCache: false,
  })
```

Comment: If you disable noScaleCache, scaling by the left side of the rect ends up moving the right side of the rect slightly. If you move quickly out from the left, you can move the right side further.

https://codepen.io/carter485/pen/YdaNpV

How can this be fixed? The right side should stay in place while the left side is being dragged.